# CSR8645 3.2 bluetooth module audio output merge negative pins

Tags: audio, bluetooth, automotive, digital-audio

I want to use this module with my car aux in which is has 3.5mm 3 pole jack. This module has separate negative pins as LN and RN. I need to merge and connect these pins to aux in common negative pin.
[image: Wikitech Aux Adapter]
[image: CSR8645 3.2 bt module]

Comment: Have you tried connecting them?

Comment: I haven't connected the circuit yet.

Answer (score 0):

The outputs are likely to be BTL (Bridge-Tied Load) meaning the negative outputs have a signal at the same DC level but opposite in AC polarity.  This adds 6dB to the max output level and eliminates the need for coupling caps.

If so, in order to use them single-ended, ignore RN/LN (do NOT ground them!) and capacitively couple RP and LP (which I assume are the names of the positive outputs) to your line inputs.  With luck, the amp CSR put on there will have fairly low common-mode noise.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explaination but my knowledge isn't enought to understand this :( LP and RP are positive outputs so I'll connect them as is and I won't use LN and RN negative outpus. What should I use for aux negative input? Is this behavior decrease volume level of sound?

Comment: Your negative pin (sleeve?) will be ground.  Be sure both LP and RP are connected with capacitors in series.  Make the caps large enough to cover the input impedance of your aux lines so you can get to whatever your target minimum frequency is.